# Access Secrets Manager from private container in Fargate (Terraform)

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have scoured the docs and Stackoverlow, and yet I still get this error trying to set a secret in Fargate. This error pops up in the web console for AWS in trying to launch the service.

```
ResourceInitializationError: unable to pull secrets or registry auth: execution resource retrieval failed: unable to retrieve secret from asm: service call has been retried 5 time(s): failed to fetch secret arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:xxx:secret:example_secret_1-e88LWc from secrets manager: RequestCanceled: request context canceled caused by: context deadline exceeded
```

Here is my Terraform code with the minimum to reproduce. It is not designed to be a fully working solution, but one that shows the error. I'm not sure what I am missing here.

```
data "aws_caller_identity" "current_user" {}
variable "aws_region" {
  default = "us-east-1"
}

#### Secrets

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "secrets_access" {
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "secretsmanager:GetSecret",
      "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue"
    ]
    resources = [
      "arn:aws:secretsmanager:${var.aws_region}:${data.aws_caller_identity.current_user.account_id}:secret:*"
    ]
  }
}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "example_secret" {
  name = "example_secret_1"
}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "example_secret" {
  secret_id = aws_secretsmanager_secret.example_secret.id
  secret_string = "example_value2"
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "secrets_access" {
  name = "access-secrets"
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.secrets_access.json
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "secrets_access" {
  role = aws_iam_role.execution_role.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.secrets_access.arn
}

# Secrets Manager Endpoint
resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "secrets_manager" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.example_vpc.id
  service_name = "com.amazonaws.${var.aws_region}.secretsmanager"
  vpc_endpoint_type = "Interface"
  private_dns_enabled = true
  security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.open_access.id]
  auto_accept = true
}

resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "s3" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.example_vpc.id
  service_name = "com.amazonaws.${var.aws_region}.s3"
  vpc_endpoint_type = "Interface"
  security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.open_access.id]
  auto_accept = true
}

resource "aws_security_group" "open_access" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.example_vpc.id
  name_prefix = "secrets-manager"
  ingress {
    from_port = 0
    to_port = 65535
    protocol = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  egress {
    from_port = 0
    to_port = 65335
    protocol = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}


# Cluster + VPC

resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "example" {
  name = "test-cluster"
}

# Define your VPC resources
resource "aws_vpc" "example_vpc" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
  enable_dns_support = true
  enable_dns_hostnames = true
  tags = {
    Name = "example_vpc"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "example_subnet" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.example_vpc.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.1.0/24"
  availability_zone = "${var.aws_region}a"
  tags = {
    Name = "example_subnet"
  }
}


# Service related
data "aws_ami" "ecs_optimized" {
  most_recent = true

  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["amzn-ami-*-amazon-ecs-optimized"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "virtualization-type"
    values = ["hvm"]
  }

  owners = ["amazon"]
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "ecs_agent" {
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"]
    }
    effect = "Allow"
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "execution_role" {
  name = "ecs_agent"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.ecs_agent.json
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "example_task_definition" {
  family = "example_task"
  cpu = 512
  memory = 1024
  container_definitions = jsonencode([{
    name = "example_container"
    image = "hello-world"
    secrets = [{
      name = "example_secret"
      valueFrom = aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.example_secret.arn
    }]
    portMappings = [{
      containerPort = 80
      hostPort = 80
    }]
  }])
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  network_mode = "awsvpc"
  execution_role_arn = aws_iam_role.execution_role.arn
}

resource "aws_security_group" "example_service" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.example_vpc.id

  ingress {
    from_port = 80
    to_port = 80
    protocol = "tcp"
  }

  egress {
    from_port = 443
    to_port = 443
    protocol = "tcp"
  }
}

resource "aws_ecs_service" "example_service" {
  name = "example_service"
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.example_task_definition.arn
  desired_count = 1
  launch_type = "FARGATE"
  cluster = aws_ecs_cluster.example.name
  network_configuration {
    security_groups = [aws_security_group.example_service.id]
    subnets = [aws_subnet.example_subnet.id]
  }
}
```

Comment: The error is thrown by TF or your application? What is the full error message?

Comment: Did you put the task in public subnet?
If you used private subnet, did you create SSM VPC endpoint and allow security group from ECS tasks?

Comment: Also your VPC is fully private. So how exactly do you expect ECS to download `hello-world` container?

Comment: @Marcin this error is being thrown on launch and is reported in the AWS web console. I'll update the question. I get the same error with an Internet gateway attached, too - so this is probably happening before it tries to download the image.

Comment: @HùngNguyễn I do not wish to assign the task a public IP address. All the endpoints I am attempting to create are in the code. Which SSM are you talking about? For AWS that acronym is ambiguous.